# Magento: How to get the product "Minimum Sale Quantity" To Show

Tags: magento

Magento 1.7 in the code below I'm trying to get the product attribute "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" to display to the front end. What am I missing? Thanks

```
<dl class="product-sku">
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__('Product SKU') ?>:</dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSKU(), 'sku') ?></dd>

                    <dt><?php echo $this->__('Dimensions') ?>:</dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDimensions(), 'dimensions') ?></dd>

                    <dt><?php echo $this->__('Configuration') ?>:</dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getConfiguration(), 'configuration') ?></dd>

                    <dt><?php echo $this->__('Minimum Purchase Quantity') ?>:</dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getMinSaleQty(), 'min_sale_qty') ?></dd>
                </dl>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
$productQuantity = Mage::getModel("cataloginventory/stock_item")
->loadByProduct($_product->getId());
```

And your minimun qty its here....

```
$productQuantity->getMinSaleQty();
```

Comment: Guerra thanks for the help I did that and got the list. Oddly nothing on there referencing the Min Sale Qty http://jsfiddle.net/YdnzF/2/

Comment: I forgot, all about quantity on product its managed by catalog_inventory/stock_item, i've edited the aswer to the right.

Comment: Typo "cataloginvetory" - change to "cataloginventory"

Answer (score 0):

A loaded product model contains `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item Object` which handles the stock and inventory information. The way I like to handle this is:

```
$minsale = $_product->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty();
```