# magento add minimum buyable qty from category listing

Tags: magento

I have this situation where for all products in the store I have set a minimum of 50 products for a user to buy. This works fine when the user goes to the detail page and adds the product in cart, however if he pushes the button from category listing there is only 1 product added.

This triggers an error in the checkout making the user to increase the amount of products in the current basket.

Is there any way I can make the system add to cart 50 products at once if the user is adding from category listing page?

Magento is 1.5 CE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Add to Cart Url of Product at listing has qty parameter then it will directly add product to cart with given quantity like `http://domain/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/###/product/17/form_key/###/qty/50/`

In `{theme}template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product,array('qty'=>$_minimalQty)) ?>
```

will do this trik.

Now to get minimum sale quantity at listing page you can follow this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047030/magento-how-to-get-the-product-minimum-sale-quantity-to-show#answer-12047700)

Comment: Thank you! I have seen the link that you posted but I do not want to display the number in the category. Actually the URL is custom and the checkout page looks like "domain.com/checkout/cart/" and there is no qty in the url.

Comment: Even if the URL is custom, you have to append qty/$_minimalQty at the end of URL one or the other way, to get it working